# find last two amounts of each customer based on dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

### |          recharge_table        |

| r_date | r_name | r_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | Phineas | 120 |
| 01-02-2020 | Phineas | 130 |
| 01-03-2020 | Phineas | 199 |
| 01-04-2020 | Candes | 299 |
| 03-01-2020 | Candes | 149 |
| 03-02-2020 | Ferb | 149 |
| 03-03-2020 | Platypus | 349 |
| 05-08-2020 | Ferb | 459 |
| 09-11-2020 | Candes | 199 |
| 06-10-2020 | Platypus | 299 |

find last two amounts of each customer based on dates, and in ascending order of name.

output must be as below:-

```
| Candes   | 199 | 299 |
| Ferb     | 459 | 159 |
| Phineas  | 199 | 130 |
| Platypus | 299 | 349 |
```

If Possible, also give explanation.

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. [[tag:mysql]] and [[tag:sql-server]] are completely different products, and [[tag:mysql-workbench]] is an IDE that only works with the former.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select r_name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then r_amount end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then r_amount end)
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by r_name order by r_date desc) as seqnum
      from recharge_table r
     ) r
where seqnum <= 2
group by r_name;
```